# Service Endpoint between 2 Azure VMs?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine, endpoint, azure-virtual-network, azure-vm

In Azure, Can we enable service endpoint to talk between 2 IaaS resources(2 Azure VMs) like below ?  .

As far as I understand service endpoint is useful in accessing only PaaS Services via the Vnet

As far as i understand , The Azure VMs can talk over the VNet and no need of service endpoint .  Even when i look in the subnet configuration, i see ServiceEndpoints to only PaaS services like ServiceBus, Azure SQL , Azure Storage etc.  So i think having service endpoint between 2 VMs is technically not correct. Please advise.

https://blog.coeo.com/azure-service-endpoints

Please advise
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service endpoints are between Vnet and azure PaaS services like Service Bus , azure SQL , azure web app etc. It's not for use between 2 VM.
If the 2 VMs are in same Vnet ,then can communicate, else there should be Vnet peering between the vnets.

Answer (score 0):

By default, Azure allows communication between resources under same VNET but in different subnets until unless there is specific NSG blocker on these subnets.

Today we provide service endpoints as a solution for PaaS services where there is a limitation on public access.

Unlike Service Endpoints, Private Link allows access to a specific PaaS resource in your virtual network.